# Why are Valerian and Laureline so young, yet have such high ranking positions?

Tags: character, valerian-city-of-a-thousand-planets

In the movie, *Valerian and the City of a Thousand Planets* (2017), Valerian has the rank of major and Laureline is a sergeant. Yet, they seem so young. Is it just that the intended audience is younger, so younger actors were chosen to identify with?

Comment: They're way behind Ender from _Ender's Game_. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ranking system is the same in the future, major and sergeant aren't that high up. And age isn't really a factor so much as your ability to handle the privileges and responsibilities of the rank.

Clearly Valarian and Lauralene earned their ranks.